# using `dplyr::tally` when column name "n" is present in the dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am working with the development version of `dplyr` and struggling with using `dplyr::tally` when there is a column name `"n"` present in the dataframe.

- **dplyr `0.8.5`** (CRAN version)

This was not an issue in prior version.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% dplyr::group_by(am) %>% tally(., wt = NULL, name = "n_obs")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      am n_obs
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     0    19
#> 2     1    13

df <- dplyr::rename(.data = mtcars, n = wt)

df %>% dplyr::group_by(am) %>% tally(., wt = NULL, name = "n_obs")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      am n_obs
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     0    19
#> 2     1    13
```

- **dplyr `1.0.0`** (GitHub version)

But it no longer produces the right output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% dplyr::group_by(am) %>% tally(., wt = NULL, name = "n_obs")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      am n_obs
#> * <dbl> <int>
#> 1     0    19
#> 2     1    13

df <- dplyr::rename(.data = mtcars, n = wt)

df %>% dplyr::group_by(am) %>% tally(., wt = NULL, name = "n_obs")
#> Using `n` as weighting variable
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      am n_obs
#> * <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0  71.6
#> 2     1  31.3
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: the reference for `tally` in `dplyr 1.0.0` specifically states: "If omitted, and column n exists, it will automatically be used as a weighting variable, although you will have to specify name to provide a new name for the output." This is somewhat different from what it says in `dplyr 0.8.5`. Stikes me as a non-optimal change. You could raise this as an issue on the dplyr github.

Comment: If you run the code without the `name` argument, it raises an error: `Error: Column 'n' is already present in output` and  `Use 'name = "new_name"' to pick a new name`. This was *not* the case in `dplyr 0.8.5` so the change seems quite intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation (as pointed out in the comments), the previous workflow seems to be impossible to recover.

So here is a workaround:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% summarize(n = dplyr::n())
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      am     n
#> * <dbl> <int>
#> 1     0    19
#> 2     1    13

df <- dplyr::rename(.data = mtcars, n = wt)

df %>% dplyr::group_by(am) %>% summarize(n = dplyr::n())
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      am     n
#> * <dbl> <int>
#> 1     0    19
#> 2     1    13
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Related issue on `GitHub` by someone else:
https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5108